# Profile model (extending custom user model) not getting registered in django admin

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

***I am new to django and totally confused so what should i do for these..***

Note- `list_display = ('email', 'first_name',)` `'email', 'first_name'` which defined in custom user model **User**

1. I am not getting errors but it not registering the **Profile** model
   to admin why?
2. if i am adding `phone` from **Profile** model to `list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'phone')` i m getting error `(admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[2]' refers to 'phone', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'UserAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'users.User'.` How can i add `phone` in list_display?
3. I uses `post_save_user_model_receiver()` to auto create profile when
   user is created is it best way to do it?
4. how can i add all `Profile` model fields for edit/update in **users.admin** (which is below).

**profile model**

```
from django.db import models
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model  # or from users.models import User

User = get_user_model()

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    city    = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    bio     = models.TextField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.email)


def post_save_user_model_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs ):
    if created:
        try:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)  # it create those user's profile
        except:
            pass

post_save.connect(post_save_user_model_receiver, sender=User)
```

**Admin**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from .models import Profile

User = get_user_model()


# Define an inline admin descriptor for Employee model
# which acts a bit like a singleton
class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'profile'


# Define a new User admin
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    inlines = (ProfileInline,)
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name',)
    list_filter = ('admin', 'staff', 'active')
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()

# Re-register UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

**users.admin file**

```html
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model   # or from .models import User
from .forms import UserAdminCreationForm, UserAdminChangeForm
# Register your models here.

User = get_user_model()   # or from .models import User


class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    # The forms to add and change user instances
    form = UserAdminChangeForm
    add_form = UserAdminCreationForm

    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'get_phone', 'last_login', 'date_joined', 'is_admin')
    list_filter = ('admin', 'staff', 'active')
    list_select_related = ('profile',)

    def get_phone(self, instance):       # to show the Phone in list display from the Profile Model
        return instance.profile.phone
    get_phone.short_description = 'Phone'

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal Info', {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name',)}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('admin', 'staff', 'active')}),
    )
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2', )
        }
        ),
    )
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()


admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)

# Remove Group Model from admin. We're not using it.
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

Comment: What happens when you open a User inside your admin app?

Comment: @arthursribeiro its working fine.